# Webservice Error from remote system

Tags: asp.net, web-services

Could any one help me in finding the solution for this error.

I have a normal web service which is working fine in intranet, when when the vendors try to access the same from internet, they get this below error.

---

> There was an error downloading
>   'https://isite.corp.net/Service/Sample.asmx'.
>
> The remote name could not be resolved:
>   'isite.corp.net'
>
> Metadata contains a reference that
>   cannot be resolved:
>   'https://isite.corp.net/Service/Sample.asmx'.
>
> There was no endpoint listening at
>   https://isite.corp.net/Service/Sample.asmx
>   that could accept the message. This is
>   often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action. See InnerException, if
>   present, for more details.
>
> The remote name could not be resolved:
>   'isite.corp.net'
>
> If the service is defined in the
>   current solution, try building the
>   solution and adding the service
>   reference again.

---

Does any one know the solution for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like domain "isite.corp.net" (website) is not accessible from outside office network because error says  "The remote name could not be resolved: 'isite.corp.net'".  Please make sure your domain is public and can be accessible from outside.  If it is not public, you have ask your vendor to put ipaddress mapping in host file.